# touchmove and touchstart and the 300ms delay

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap-build

i am converting a web app to android using phonegap and i am using this to control a cursor

```
$(document).on('touchmove', function (e) {


  var touch = e.originalEvent.touches["0"];



  $img.css({
    top: (touch.clientY)  - 105,
    left:  (touch.clientX) - 25,
    display: 'block'
  });

});
```

now the problem is when i touch the screen the cursor doesn't appear until i start moving my fingers and that is because i am using touchmove so i used instead touchstart and the result was when i touch the screen the cursor appears but doesn't move.

is there a solution where i can find the cursor without any delay and after touching the screen and move it perfectly ??

Comment: Have you tried listening to both `touchstart` *and* `touchmove`?

Comment: i tried repeating the above code but with touchstart  and it worked but with problems.cursor appears and after a fraction or second it starte moving

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding fastclick polyfill to your bundle, [fastclick at github](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)

then you just do

```
if ('addEventListener' in document) {
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    FastClick.attach(document.body);
}, false);}
```

or with jquery...

```
$(function() {
FastClick.attach(document.body);});
```

Comment: Isn't some kind of equivalent functionality already provided by Phonegap?